# Separate big xml into multiple small xml file

Tags: python, xml

This is the books.xml which contains all the information of books.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.10.00
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book2
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.15.40
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book3
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.435.90
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        EUR.15.40
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book2
    </Name>
    <Price>
        EUR.66.40
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        GBP.10.20
    </Price>
</Book>
</root>
```

With the given books.xml, i want it to generate multiple xml files according to the currency

Output I desire

USD_books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.10.00
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book2
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.15.40
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book3
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.435.90
    </Price>
</Book>
```

EUR_books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        EUR.15.40
    </Price>
</Book>

<Book>
    <Name>
        Book2
    </Name>
    <Price>
        EUR.66.40
    </Price>
</Book>
```

GDP_books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        GBP.10.20
    </Price>
</Book>
```

The output I am getting is:

GPB_books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book>
    <Name>
        Book1
    </Name>
    <Price>
        GBP.10.20
    </Price>
</Book>
```

EUR_books.xml

```
<Book>
        <Name>
            Book2
        </Name>
        <Price>
            EUR.66.40
        </Price>
    </Book>
```

USD_books.xml

```
<Book>
    <Name>
        Book3
    </Name>
    <Price>
        USD.435.90
    </Price>
</Book>
```

My code:

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse



for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'Book':
        Price = elem.find('Price').text
        title = Price.split('.')[0].strip()
        filename = format(title + "_Books.xml")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(bytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n",'utf-8'))
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```

I need the books with the same currency to be in one xml but I keep getting the error junk after document

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how your code is supposed to work. This kind of task is easiest done with XSLT 2.0+:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//Book" 
                  group-by="substring-before(normalize-space(Price), '.')">
      <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}_books.xml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note: this produces the output you've asked for, despite the fact that the resulting files are not well-formed XML documents (they are well-formed XML fragments). Attempting to parse these files may well fail with an error saying there is unexpected content after the document element, unless you use a parser configured to parse well-formed fragments. Normally it would be usual to add a wrapper element around the sequence of Book elements, which you could do by changing the content of the `xsl:result-document` instruction to

```
<books>
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
</books>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the problem is to go through a copy of the file, remove books OTHER than those with the target currency and then save what's left...

Note that in your expected output you only have one EUR book while your xml has two.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

books = """[your xml above]"""
#get all unique currencies in the collection
currencies = set([p.text.strip().split('.')[0] for p in doc.findall('.//Price')])
for currency in currencies:
    #make a copy of the parsed file 
    cur_doc = copy.deepcopy(doc)
    for book in cur_doc.findall('.//Book'):
        if not currency in book.find('.//Price').text:
            cur_doc.remove(book)
    print(ET.tostring(cur_doc).decode())
```

The output should be your expected (correct) output. Obviously, instead of printing each one you can save it to file as you do in your question.